# Query from the same many-to-many table

Tags: mysql, database

I need to maintain a material table. Each material may has one or more alternative materials, so it would form a many-to-many relationship on the same table. Users can query the alternatives by a given material's part number.

I created two tables,as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE material (
    id int(3) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    pn varchar(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
CREATE TABLE mapping (
    pn_id int(3) NOT NULL,
    main_pn_id int(3) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (pn_id, main_pn_id)
);
ALTER TABLE mapping ADD FOREIGN KEY (pn_id) REFERENCES material (id);
ALTER TABLE mapping ADD FOREIGN KEY (main_pn_id) REFERENCES material (id);
```

My querying inputs are always pn (part number of a material). It means the select command would look like this.

```
SELECT * FROM material ..... WHERE pn="XXXXX";
```

If I'd like to find the alternatives for a given material. I need to query its id by part number first. Then I use id to find pn_id by

```
SELECT pn_id FROM mapping WHERE main_pn_id=$id
```

At last, using pn_id to find pn from material table.

I knew it can be achieved by subquery or UNION to get alternatives for a material, but using subquery and UNION may influence the querying performance. My system may be used by hundreds of people.

I tried to use JOIN to complete a querying, but I still could not figure out how to use JOIN to query alternatives in my situation. Could anyone kindly help me on this?
Thanks.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help.  it appears you just need to join to material twice once for the main mapping and once for the pn mapping.  Now if you need to traverse a hierarchy; that's a different story.  but you seem to be just asking for each main what are the parts that could be substituted.  The material and mapping data is a little vague thus I'm not sure about the exact SQl thus the desire to see sample data expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not a simple join to Material twice.

Note I used left joins here as I'm unsure if all materials would be in the mapping table.

```
SELECT M1.ID as MainPartID
     , M1.PN as MainPartNumber
     , M2.ID as AltPartID
     , M2.PN as AltPartNum
FROM material M1
LEFT JOIN Mapping Map
 on M1.ID = MAP.PN_ID
LEFT JOIN Material M2
 on M2.ID = MAP.Main_PN_ID
WHERE M1.PN = 'XXXXX'
```